# How detect the phone has been locked because of autolock time exceeded in an app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, auto-lock

I need to know if there is an event in the AppDelegate.swift that is triggered when the phone has been locked because of the autolock time exceeded

I have tried to use the applicationDidEnterBackground method but It is not triggered because in that case the app is still in foreground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `applicationWillResignActive` method in `AppDelegate` and check if `brightness` is changed to 0.0 as below,

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if UIScreen.main.brightness == 0.0 {
        print("App is locked!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way of doing this.

There are a few hacks floating around, but you shouldn't use them (your app could get rejected from the app store if you do use them).